# Probability question : How to find the actual numerical value without the lengthy calculation?

Tags: probability

> A class contains $10$ boys and $15$ girls. $8$ students are to be selected
>   at random from the class without replacement. Let X be the number of
>   boys selected and Y the number of girls selected. Find $E(X −Y )$.

I could chalk out the table:

$E(X-Y)= -8$ when $X=0$ and $Y=8$

$E(X-Y)= -7$ when $X=1$ and $Y=7$

etc etc

each with probability $\binom{25}{8}\frac{10}{25}^{x}\frac{15}{25}^{y}$

But how do i go about the lengthy calculation and find the actual expected value?

Comment: Am i missing something here, some short cut formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2219295/265466), observe that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent variables. In fact, $Y=8-X$. So $E[X-Y]=E[X-(8-X)]=E[2X-8]=2E[X]-8$. Now, $X\sim\operatorname{Hypergeometric}(10,10+15,8)$, so $E[X]=8\cdot{10\over25}=\frac{16}5$, therefore $E[X-Y]=-\frac85$.

If you don’t remember the mean of the hypergeometric distribution, another way to attack this is to observe that the distribution is exchangeable, that is, the probability depends only on the number of boys (and girls) selected, not on the order in which they were selected. Therefore, the probability of choosing a boy is order-independent: the probability that the $i$th selection is a boy is simply ${10\over25}$. If we let $B_i$ be indicator variables for these events and $G_i$ be indicator variables for the events “the $i$th choice is a girl,” then $$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^8E[B_i]=8\Pr(\text{boy is chosen}) \\ E[Y]=\sum_{i=1}^8E[G_i]=8\Pr(\text{girl is chosen}) \\ E[X-Y]=8\Pr(\text{boy is chosen})-8\Pr(\text{girl is chosen})=8\left({10\over25}-{15\over25}\right)=-\frac85.$$

Comment: Though, this is probably a 'without replacement' scenario, so won't the probability decrease as we choose more Boys? hence, Not $8*10/25$??

Comment: @Idkwoman See http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Introduction.html for an explanation of why the indicator variables have the same distribution. The basic idea is that in any given draw of $k$ boys and $8-k$ girls, a boy is equally likely to have been chosen at any step.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try $E(X)-E(Y)=E(X-Y)$

Comment: Thanks, But E(X) and E(Y) would also be lengthy calculations, How am i supposed to calculate them in exams with very limited time?

Comment: Oh yeah, i guess you could also try to write $Y$ as $8 - X$